# How to maintain ACID transaction in mongodb documents connected by ref schema

Tags: mongodb

I was going through the document given [here](https://www.mongodb.com/faq) . In this document it is clearly mentioned that MongoDB supports ACID property at particular document level, it does not give the same for interconnected documents. So suppose, if I am building my application with MEAN stack then how to make my transaction ACID which has schema interconnected via references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but, as stated in the documentation, there are no multi-document transactions in mongodb. So the answer is: "you can't do any multi-document transactions". Your client technology is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no ACID in NoSQL ?

Comment: @JasonKrs: what do you mean by "NoSQL"?

Comment: I mean "new age" DBMS ; MongoDb, Hadoop, etc... (not the "grandpas like Oracle, DB2, Mssql, mysql, posgresql, etc...)

Comment: @JasonKrs: you realize these are all different databases? And "NoSQL" is not a standard? So one can't generalize like that ("there is/isn't ACID in NoSQL").

Comment: Okay then... I'm learning MongoDb right now. I thought there was some trivial separation between legacy RDBMS and NoSQL DBMS... I guess it's not that simple. Thanks. I'm gonna research more on that.

Comment: I am talking about when there are many referenced schemas in mongodb. Then how to maintain ACID property for that?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker: do you have a specific scenario in mind?

Comment: yes, suppose I have schema A,B,C and D. All of them are connected via ref schema. Now I have defined one API which saves the data in all four schema one after another , so at that time how to maintain ACID property?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker: that would be a multi-document transaction, which mongodb doesn't have. So there's no way to do that ACIDly.

Comment: ok, now I understood it. So is there any way to make transaction atleast atomic?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker: nope, especially not atomic. But C and D might be available, depending on your settings (write concern)

Comment: Ok, then suppose transaction fails after saving data in A and B then it might break the cycle because originally it was supposed to store data in A,B,C and D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151214/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-mrugesh-thaker).